# Convert XML to JSON without json_encode in PHP

Tags: php, json, simplexml

I am trying to convert XML to JSON without using json_encode/json_decode. I have the following code, bear in mind that I am new to PHP and JSON.

```
<?php
$myXMLData = 
"<test>
   <info>
      <sample>
         <sampleOne>test</sampleOne>
         <sampleTwo>test two</sampleTwo>
         <values value='today'>
            <sampleThree>test three</sampleThree>
            <sampleFour>test four</sampleFour>
                <sampleFive>
                    <sampleSix>test six</sampleSix>
                </sampleFive>   
         </values>
      </sample>
    </info>
</test>";

$contents=simplexml_load_string($myXMLData) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

//print_r($contents);

echo '{"' . $contents->getName() . '":{"';

foreach ($contents->children() as $child1)
{ 
    $child1->count();
    echo $child1->getName() . '": {"';
    echo $child1->attributes();
    echo $child1[0];

    foreach ($child1->children() as $child2)
    { 
        $child2->count();
        echo $child2->getName() . '": {"';
        echo $child2->attributes();
        echo $child2[0] . ": ";

        foreach ($child2->children() as $child3)
        {
            $child3->count();
            echo $child3->getName() . '": {"';
            echo $child3->attributes();
            echo $child3[0];

            foreach ($child3->children() as $child4)
            { 
                $child4->count();
                echo $child4->getName();
                echo $child4->attributes();
                echo $child4[0];


                foreach ($child4->children() as $child5)
                {
                    echo $child5->getName();
                    echo $child5->attributes();
                    echo $child5[0];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
echo "}";
?>
```

The results should look like a JSON file but I am stuck here.

```
{
  "test": {
    "info": {
      "sample": {
        "sampleOne": "test",
        "sampleTwo": "test two",
        "values": {
          "-value": "today",
          "sampleThree": "test three",
          "sampleFour": "test four",
          "sampleFive": { "sampleSix": "test six" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure if this is a good way of doing this. But I have spent a few hours on this already and I can't seem to find a solution to this.

Comment: Just.. why would you do this without json_encode? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I know it's an actual task I have been asked to do. I tried to find the json_encode file to see how they do it. But not sure where to look.

Comment: @Dino Is there a perspective to change those requirements?

Comment: Yeah, it's a ridiculous requirement. Even more so if you're still allowed to use SimpleXML. If you want to look at how it's done in PHP, you can try and back trace through the C code. https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/49a4e695845bf55e059e7f88e54b1111fe284223/ext/json/json.c

Comment: @Yoshi sadly not. I can do it anyway but I cannot use json_encode/decode

Comment: @Dino Ok, so as it stands, your main problem is recursively traversing the simplexml object and producing the required output?

Comment: @Yoshi yes that is correct, I am still searching for some kind of solution. But with my basic knowledge of PHP, it's difficult.

Comment: Looks like the learning task for recursion. Why don't you google the solution if you want to cheat? There are at least several solutions on the Internet. Foreach in foreach is not a solution. Think about recursion -> you need to do the same things on every node.

Comment: @ViktarPryshchepa thanks for that tip, I knew it wasn't a solution. I did not know about recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, recursion is the way to go here. You basically need a function that gets a SimpleXMLElement as a parameter and calls itself recursively with each child as argument. This should give you an idea of how to do it (no attribute handling and no commata for multiple children though):

```
$masterNode = simplexml_load_string($string);
convertNodeToJSON($masterNode);

function convertNodeToJSON($node) {
    if ($node->count === 0) { // the current node is text
        echo '"' . $node->getName() . '"';
        return;
    }
    echo '{ "' . $node->getName() . '" : ';
    foreach ($node->attributes as $attr) {
        // handle attributes
    }
    foreach ($node->children() as $child) {
        convertNodeToJSON($child);
        // add a comma if necessary
    }
    echo "}";
}
```

The code is not tested, but it's just a starting point anyways. Hope this helps :)